# How to print the strings in an array?

Tags: java

At the moment I have an array of

```
public Module[]moduleArray = new Module[4];
```

and to output it i'm using

```
public void displayModules()
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < moduleArray.length; i++)
    {
       System.out.println(moduleArray[i]); 
    }        
 }
```

However it's outputting

> Module@1f5e4ae5
>   Module@67871079
>   null
>   null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement / override `toString()` in the `Module` class. When you see the `Module@xyz` String representation it is because the only implementation of `toString()` for the `Module` class is the `Object` class's implementation. Since `Object` doesn't know anything about `Module` it just outputs the class name and an instance id.

Comment: It should be noted, since @user979236 mentioned it in the question, that calling `toString()` on an array element that is `null` will result in a `NullPointerException`. You might need to be prepared to handle such cases.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, not true, because John does not say "call toString".  `toString` is called by Java on the object in the array.  If the object in the array is null the user will see `null`.  An NPE will not be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The class `Module` needs a meaningful `toString()` method.  What you're seeing is the output of the default `Object.toString()` method.  For example, if `Module` had String properties `name` and `type` you could have a `toString` method like:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
  return "Module named: " + name + " of type: " + type;
}
```

You would then see the String returned above instead of the output of the default `toString` method.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding `toString()` method in array's content class, in your example `Module` class, will help you to print every value from array while iterating array.

There is quick way to print arrays content without iterating over array elements, convert array to list using `Arrays.asList()` utility method.

```
System.out.println("Convert Array to List " + Arrays.asList(moduleArray));
```